# List of Persons duplicates removal with composite key

Tags: xslt, duplicates, key, xslt-3.0

I have a list of persons (10.000) with duplicates. I want to check whether the person already exists based on forename, surname and either year of birth or year of death. In that case it should write the duplicate inside the first occurrence and delete the other entry.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listperson>
    <person>
        <persName>
            <surname>Shakespeare</surname>
            <forename>William</forename>
        </persName>
        <birth>
            <date>1564-04</date>
        </birth>
        <death>
            <date>1616-05-03</date>
        </death>
    </person>
    <person>
        <persName>
            <surname>Plato</surname>
            <forename/>
        </persName>
        <birth>
            <date>-0427</date>
        </birth>
        <death>
            <date>-0347</date>
            <placeName/>
        </death>
    </person>
    <person>
        <persName>
            <surname>Shakespeare</surname>
            <forename>William</forename>
        </persName>
        <birth>
            <date>1564</date>
        </birth>
        <death>
            <date>1616-05-03</date>
        </death>
    </person>
    <person>
        <persName>
            <surname>Tolstoi</surname>
            <forename>Leo N.</forename>
        </persName>
        <birth>
            <date>1828-09-28</date>
        </birth>
        <death>
            <date>1910-11-07</date>
        </death>
    </person>
    <person>
        <persName>
            <surname>Tolstoi</surname>
            <forename>Leo N.</forename>
        </persName>
        <death>
            <date>1910-11-20</date>
        </death>
    </person>
</listperson>
```

Now the XSLT. Note I can use XSLT 3. I have not managed to write the condition properly. This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="key-birth" composite="yes" match="person"
        use="persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4)"/>

    <xsl:key name="key-death" composite="yes" match="person"
        use="persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(death/date, 1, 4)"/>


    <xsl:template
        match="XXXX">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when
                test="XXXX forename+surname+year of birth">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    <xsl:element name="duplicate">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="XXXX"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when
                test="XXXX forename+surname+year of death">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    <xsl:element name="duplicate">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="XXXX"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

I managed to achieve some results before with using following-sibling:: and preceding-sibling:: but that is slow and had some strange results, so I hope someone here can point me to a solution with keys, maybe with generate-id()?

The output of course should move the duplicates of Shakespeare and Tolstoi into the first occurrence. In the next step I would merge them and check for differences, e.g. the date of Tolstois death is different in the two entries.

Comment: Note that Tolstoi is showing with two different forenames; "Leo N. von" and "Leo N." so these will not be considered as duplicates, unless you wanted to expand the logic to only look at the very first part of the name (before the first space). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i corrected the name so that they are the same.

Comment: It is not quite clear which output you want. What happens if there a certain person has duplicates based on birth date as well death date? Do you want two outputs of the person, one with the duplicates based on the birth date inside and the other with the duplicates based on death date inside? Or just one person output with both kind of duplicates inside?

Comment: You are right: I want to detect duplicates based on name and year of birth and/or year of death and want the nodes copied as a child-element 'duplicate' to the first entry. The duplicate should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` to copy existing nodes, so instead of thinking about copying distinct values, you should think about excluding the duplicates from copying. One way to do this, is use templates to ignore them. For example, to ignore duplicates based on birth date do this.

```
<xsl:template match="person[. except key('key-birth', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4)))[1]]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="key-birth" composite="yes" match="person"
        use="persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4)"/>

    <xsl:key name="key-death" composite="yes" match="person"
        use="persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(death/date, 1, 4)"/>

    <xsl:template match="person[. except key('key-birth', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4)))[1]]" />

    <xsl:template match="person[. except key('key-death', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(death/date, 1, 4)))[1]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you want to add a `duplicates` node to the distinct person elements remaining, add this template to the XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="person">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <duplicates>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('key-birth', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4))) except .|key('key-death', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(death/date, 1, 4))) except ." />
    </duplicates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh31

Comment: This does indeed delete the duplicates. But the problem is, that I want the duplicate entry included as a child element so that I can check for mistakes.

Comment: Your solution works as desired! I only moved those two lines into one to get rid of the "ambiguous rule match": <xsl:template match="person[. except key('key-birth', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(birth/date, 1, 4)))[1]]|person[. except key('key-death', (persName/surname, persName/forename, substring(death/date, 1, 4)))[1]]" />

Comment: Ah yes, of course. You could also have added a `priority="2"` to one of the templates if you wanted to keep them separate.